# Two successive recursions explanation needed

Tags: python, recursion

The following code is for finding all subsets for a given list.

```
def sublist(big_list, selected_so_far):
    if big_list == []:
        print (selected_so_far)
    else:
        current = big_list[0]
        rest = big_list[1:]
        sublist(rest, selected_so_far+[current])
        sublist(rest, selected_so_far)
```

If the input is "sublist([1,2,3], [])" it will output like this:

1. [1, 2, 3]
2. [1, 2]
3. [1, 3]
4. [1]
5. [2, 3]
6. [2]
7. [3]
8. []

I understand that for the first recursive call it ends at printing line no.1 but can't figure out how the second recursive call prints out all those remaining lines. Can someone please explain the flow of this code?

Comment: The best method to understand `Recursion` methods , **trace it**!

Comment: you are just creating a powerset of the list in top to down format.